# zend framewok 2 doctrine 2 , naming strategy to underscore

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

where do i have to add this code to change the naming strategy to UnderscoreNamingStrategy in doctrine 2 with zend framework 2

```
 $namingStrategy = new MyNamingStrategy();
$configuration()->setNamingStrategy($namingStrategy);
```

i have no yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
    use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader,
        Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache,
        Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
        Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
        Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;

    $config = new Configuration;
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl(new ArrayCache());
    $driverImpl = new AnnotationDriver(new AnnotationReader(), '/path/to/entities');
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
    $config->setNamingStrategy(new MyNamingStrategy());

    $connectionOptions = array(
        'url' => 'sqlite:///:memory:'
    );

    $this->entityManager = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your module.config.php

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'configuration' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'naming_strategy' => UnderscoreNamingStrategy::class,
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            UnderscoreNamingStrategy::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```